# camelCase methods, under_score method parameters

Tags: php, coding-style, naming-conventions

Here's a function [declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) that belongs to PHP's [PDOStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) class:

```
public function bindValue ($parameter, $value, $data_type = 'PDO::PARAM_STR')
```

It demonstrates something peculiar about the coding style that the PDOStatmenet and a few other PHP classes use - method names (as well as class and instance variables) use camelCase while parameter variables - under_score.

Does this coding style follow any particular coding / naming convention?

Comment: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php

Comment: To my knowledge it just follows tradition. Although I've seen a few research papers about it which seem to vary the results. Here's one: http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/camelcase-vs-underscores-scientific-showdown/

Comment: @AyeshK, This is not it - it uses clamelCase for parameters.

Comment: @WilliamIsted, How is this relevant to the question?

Comment: *"I don't understand why people keep complaining about a lack of conventions in PHP, there are so many of them!"*

Comment: @deceze Where is this quote from?

Comment: @Haralan Don't remember unfortunately. It's fitting though.

Comment: @deceze It's possibly a paraphrase of "The nice thing about standards is that you have so many to choose from." from [Andrew_S._Tanenbaum](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Andrew_S._Tanenbaum)

Comment: PHP's coding "conventions" are all but non-existent. Function names can be underscore_style (`file_get_contents()`), C style (`strlen()`) or camelCase (as in your example). It's hideous and it nearly makes me cry :(

Comment: In the absence of any authoritative answer confirming this conforms to a particular standard, and given our familiarity with PHP's lack of "convention" in general, I'm sure everyone's intuition (including yours?) is that someone just jumbled up some standards in their mouth and sneezed on the screen.  Can I just answer "no", and get the votes? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The **[PHP Framework Interoperability Group (FIG)](http://www.php-fig.org/)** created a standard **[PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md)** (Basic coding standard for PHP which aims to ensure a high level of technical interoperability between shared PHP code.). This douments this style of formatting for class constants and methods. [Please see section 4 of the guide](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#4-classes-properties-and-methods).

FIG was formed in 2009 and is [formed of a number of developers of PHP frameworks](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards#voting-members). They convene and develop standards to improve interoperability and coding style between frameworks. They are not an 'official' standard but the aim is to influence a large cross-section of the PHP community. In my opinion, this standard is very firmly established in the world of PHP5.3+.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: In that it follows PSR-1 coding convention.

Comment: Nope, not really - it does not specify style for parameter variables nor explains why class and instance variables have different style than parameter variables.

Comment: Fair point, I had mis-read your comment on parameter variables (arguments) and the style demonstrated in your example.

Comment: With regards to an explanation on styling you did not state this in your question 'Does this coding style follow any particular coding / naming convention?'.

Comment: The document does however state the following 'This guide intentionally avoids any recommendation regarding the use of $StudlyCaps, $camelCase, or $under_score property names.

Whatever naming convention is used SHOULD be applied consistently within a reasonable scope. That scope may be vendor-level, package-level, class-level, or method-level.'

Comment: Sure, it states that, but peculiar thing about the style I ask about is the fact that it combines camelCase with under_score and, unfortunately, PSR-1 has nothing to do with that.